# get YouTube music video metadata

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working for a school project where we have to play music videos from YouTube with data about these videos from Wikipedia; the difficult part is to identify the music in the video (for a human it is very simple, but a computer can't just understand it from the title). After a lot of useless searches on Google that lead me to desperation, I noticed that in the description of the video there is a `div` (`ytd-metadata-row-container-renderer`) containing the information I need for the project (it contains category, license and music - the exact title of the song and the author). Is it possible to get these data with a YouTube API, Ajax request or other methods? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is not available in the YouTube Data API v3.

Comment: I did create a entry in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122506827) they *(Google)* manage. You'll need log in with your gmail account to see the issue.

Comment: Did you still looking for a answer for your question? if so, please [edit] your question and explain the following: `we have to play music videos from youtube with data about these videos from wikipedia` = how are you doing this? it's no clear to me, IMHO. If you can provide a clear example about how you're proceeding, I might be able to help you.

Comment: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74652266) the same question on StackOverflow, let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.