# Getting Artist name an Genre from the YouTube Video

Tags: api, youtube

Is there any way to get the Artist name and Genre of YouTube video using REST API? I tried with all APIs provided by YouTube/Google but no solution yet.

Wondering if there are any third party solutions.

For example, I want the artist name as per the screenshot from the song

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgJ9rHIIRQg

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that kind of info is not available in the results provided by the YouTube Data API. Did you try something else?, if so, [edit] the question. This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50307229/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using 2 ways:

1. You could use the below source for getting video data:

http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html

2. You could also use request library to get html content and parse content using `BeautifulSoup`.

---

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a=requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgJ9rHIIRQg') #getting data
soup = BeautifulSoup(a) #parsing data
soup.findAll('div')
```